# What is the significance of an underscore in Perl ($_, @_)?

Tags: perl

I am new to Perl, and I used them like this

`$_`

```
foreach (@list) {
    print "$_\n";
}
```

`@_`

```
sub search {
    my ($no, @list) = @_;
}
```

How exactly do these underscore variables work in Perl? What are the other constructs where they are useful?

Comment: [perldoc perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html), [perldoc perlsyn](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html)

Comment: It sounds like you could make a lot more use of an introduction to perl essentials than StackOverflow answers. Have you been to http://learn.perl.org/ ? There are resources there including official Perl documentation, Perl books (including Beginning Perl free online) and high-quality online tutorials.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

This is the sort of question which indicates you *really* should be reading a book, and perhaps the rest of the Perl tag [FAQs](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/perl/faq).

Nevertheless, `$_` is a context variable which is created implicitly by certain constructs and used implicitly by certain built-in functions. Here are some examples:

```
while(<>) {
    next if /^#/;
    last if /^q(?:uit)?$/;
    say "Howdy!" if /^hello$/;
}
```

This doing a lot of work setting and inspecting the `$_` variable and is equivalent to:

```
while(defined($_ = <>)) {
    next if $_ =~ /^#/;
    last if $_ =~ /^q(?:uit)?$/;
    say "Howdy!" if $_ =~ /^hello$/;
}
```

Other constructs which set `$_` are: `foreach` loops, `given` blocks, `map` and `grep` operations, and `catch` blocks in [Try::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Try::Tiny).

Other constructs which use `$_` are: bare `print;` statements, the `s///` substitution operator and the `tr///` transliteration operator.

I'd advise this: while you are learning Perl, don't use `$_` implicitly. Write it all out in full (as in the second example above), to reinforce in your mind what is actually going on. Just like when you are learning a foreign language, you should learn to speak properly and carefully before you learn to abbrv y'language.

`$_` is useful for writing shorter, terser code, and can actually be clearer by focussing on the processing going on rather than the variables it is being done to, but only once you have learned as second nature which operations are using `$_`. Otherwise it's just a confusing mess.

As mentioned elsewhere, `@_` is the argument list to a subroutine.

Comment: As the OP has noticed, sometimes `print`'s implicit call doesn't help if one needs to add a newline afterwards. Newer Perl's have the command `say` which can act on `$_` but adds a new line for you. `use feature 'say'` or `use 5.10.0` to enable. Philip, I know you know this as it is in your example, I was just stating for completeness.

Comment: File::Find::find also sets `$_`; I'm not sure I would list modules that set $_ here, though; they aren't "constructs".

Comment: Your `book` link is now dead.

Answer (score 5):

Those are special variables in Perl. Refer to *[Perl - Special Variables](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_special_variables.htm)*.

Answer (score 4):

This question always comes up, because it's Perl auto-magic (I made up that term).

```
foreach (@array_list){
  print $_ . "\n";
}
```

Is equivalent to:

```
foreach my $item (@array_list){
  print $item . "\n";
}
```

The difference is that when no variable is supplied for the loop, Perl automatically sets the default `$_` to provide each item.

Similarly when calling subroutines (or methods - {subroutine in an object}) Perl puts the arguments to the subroutine in the `@_` array, since arguments will always be a list.

On the flip side, when a built-in subroutine (or any well-written subroutine) requires arguments and is called with no arguments, it will usually function on `$_` or `@_` depending on if it's expecting one or many arguments.  Some subroutines/methods (AKA functions) may work on either scalar or list values, and they usually default to scalar context and function on `$_` by default. Sometimes the name makes it clear that it expects a list (array or hash) and then it defaults to `@_` as its input.

Keep in mind, the flip side is talking about subroutine inputs, and their output depends on additional factors.  In fact, subroutine outputs usually set `$_` or `@_` simply by returning a scalar value or list values.

For more on how to write a subroutine that returns values based on context check out `wantarray` and here's a good breakdown of it:

*[Advanced Subroutine Techniques](https://www.perl.com/pub/2006/02/23/advanced_subroutines.html/)*